# picasa photo gallery for google gadget

Tags: picasa, google-gadget

i'm trying to create a nice picasa photo gallery gadget, sth like this: 
https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/image-galleries/thumbnail-viewer

but their method is to add every single picture manually. I'm wondering is there method to automatically retrieve photos from a specific album and display? (with the similar layout in the link)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.  There's no way that I know of.  I've worked a lot with Picasa photo embedding in my gadgets, and EVERYTHING has to be done manually...  I would recommend using Flickr and then researching their APIs.  That may make a large job less boring and get it done faster.